# social.frameworkを使わないSNSの実装

Tags: objective-c, social-framework

`social.framework`を使ってFacebookとTwitterに投稿できる機能を作ったのですが、投稿の際のiOS標準のダイアログを表示させたくなく、`social.framework`を使わない実装に切り替えたいと思っています。しかし、調べてみてもどうすればいいか分からず困っています。僕がやりたいこととしては、「ユーザにIDとPassを入力させて認証が通ると定型文が投稿される」という流れです。ひょっとして`social.framework`を使ったままでも上記の流れの処理は可能でしょうか？すみませんが、お返事いただけると幸いです。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

メッセージ入力用のダイアログを出したくないだけであれば`social.framework`とあわせて
`Accounts.framework`の`ACAccountStore`を使うことでOSで管理されるアカウントを使って
自前でのメッセージ投稿処理を作ることができる思います。
「socialframework ACAccountStore」で検索するとサンプルが見つかると思いますが注意点が一つ。
古いサンプルだとWebサービス側のAPIが変わっていて、そのままのコードだと投稿できなかったりします。例えばTwitterの場合、

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json
```

はでは投稿できず

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json
```

を使う必要があります（将来さらに別なものに変わるかもしれません）。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
早速ACAccountStoreを使って投稿処理を実装したいと思います。
あと、ログイン画面を表示してログインをユーザに行わせることも一緒にできますか？

Comment: ACAcountStoreを使う場合は、ログイン関連はOS側の処理となります。
すでにOS側でログインしているアカウントがあれば、それを選択できますし、ログインしているアカウントがなければ、OS側でログイン用の処理が起動します。
ログイン処理を自分で実装したい場合は、TwitterやFacebookのサイトでiOS用のSDKを無料で配布していたと思いますので、そちらをご利用になるのがよろしいかと思います。

Comment: ACAccountStoreではログイン用の処理もしてくれるのですね。
詳しく説明してくださり、ありがとうございました。
ACAccountStoreを使って実装していきたいと思います。